# Get youtube title from videoid in PHP using API v3

Tags: php, parsing, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Here is the url to to get the video info where you have to put VIDEO-ID and API-KEY:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=VIDEO-ID-HERE&key=YOUR-API-KEY-HERE
```

How to get the title from it and save it as a variable in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along these lines will get you the information related to a specific video using the PHP client library:

```
<?php

require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey('{YOUR-API-KEY}');
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$videoResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('snippet', array(
    'id' => '{YOUR-VIDEO-ID}'
));

$title = $videoResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video information</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  Title: <?= $title ?>
  </body>
 </html>
```

One more solution with API Request

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",{
            part : 'snippet', 
            id : 'VIODE_ID',
            key: 'API_KEY'},
            function(data) {
           $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
                    alert(item.snippet.title);
               });
           }
         );
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two PHP examples in [google developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).

Also, you can try a test in the bottom of this page. Input the `part`(snippet) and `id`(select one youtube id) fields. It will demonstrate to you with GET request and JSON response.